# In my bash script, how do I write a while loop that only exits if the output of "tail" doesn't contain a string?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, tail

I’m using Amazon Linux with bash shell.  In my bash script, how do I construct a while loop that will spin so long as the command

```
tail -10 /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log
```

does not contain the string “FrameworkServlet ‘myprojectDispatcher': initialization completed”?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found) might help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
tail -n 10 -f /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log |
awk '/FrameworkServlet.*myprojectDispatcher.*initialization completed/{exit} 1'
```

`awk` will exit when it encounters search string otherwise it will keep writing input to stdout.

However do keep in mind that the `tail` command is buffered and to avoid that behavior try `stdbuf` gnu utility:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tail -n 10 -f /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log |
awk '/FrameworkServlet.*myprojectDispatcher.*initialization completed/{exit} 1'
```

Comment: I tried the expressions you listed but they are not executing.  IS it because there are four single quotes in the expression, "'/FrameworkServlet ‘myprojectDispatcher': initialization completed/{exit} 1'"?

Comment: ah that's right. Try my updated answer now, I've removed internal single quotes

Answer (score 0):

I can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MATCH="FrameworkServlet ‘myprojectDispatcher': initialization completed"

while :
do
    if tail /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log | grep -q "$MATCH"; then
        exit 0
    else
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while [ -nz grep -q "FrameworkServlet ‘myprojectDispatcher': initialization completed" /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log ]; do
  # wait a second
  sleep 1
done
# do the stuff
echo "we got it!"
```